# How to track my public IP address in a log file?

Tags: networking, logs, ip

I'd like to save my public IP address to a log file so I can use them to exclude my own visit to my websites in the stats collections.
At the moment I can see my actual public IP address--[whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)--but I believe that every time I off the modem, it changes.

I don't have a static public IP address, and I think there isn't a fixed range of IP that my ISP is giving me.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3, is there any way that I've already a similar log file?
If not, can I track my future IPs and how?

Answer (score 4):

This one will give you your public IP, remove `/ip` part to see more info.

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

Comment: It doesn't show my IP history, though. @cuongnv

Comment: of course, it's not a full solution for you. But with it, you can write your own script, put that script in `cron` to make it get the IP and save into your log file.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can try to use some dynamic dns services like noip.com 
Then You can access resources by dns name, which will changing according to Your ip.</s>

Generally, Your provider may NAT with pool of addresses. And every `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` request will return a random address from this pool, depends on the settings of the NAT.

It's better to use different methods to track visits to web-site. F.e. cookies.

Here is a small python code to put in cron and collect addresses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
import os
import requests

LOG = '/tmp/ip.log'
URL = 'https://ipinfo.io/ip'

r = requests.get(URL)
if r.status_code == 200:
    ip = r.content.decode('ascii').rstrip('\n')
    last_ip = None
    if os.path.exists(LOG):
        f = open(LOG, 'r')
        last_ip = f.readlines()[-1].split()[-1]
        f.close()
    if ip != last_ip:
        f = open(LOG, 'a')
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(datetime.now(), ip))
```

Comment: Any practical example of how a dynamic-DNS service would allow OP to correlate a two week-old log entry from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with his IP address at that time?

Comment: while you do f.close() , closing the file,   in the `if os.path.exists(LOG):` condition, you forget to  in the `if ip != last_ip:` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your crontab file (`crontab -e`) to write the date and your public IPv4 address to a file called `ip_public.txt`, saved in your home directory, every day at 12:00 AM.

`0 0 * * * echo $(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d) $(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip 2>/dev/null) >> ~/ip_public.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Already an answer here, but this is another way of getting your public IP address, using DNS.

`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

You would then have to wrap it in a script, to save the history.